# Will be C++ classes exported to C# deleted by the garbage collector?

Tags: c#, c++, garbage-collection

The idea is to create and export a wrapper for the C++ class and then use it from C# like following:

First, let us create the C++ class itself:

File : MyClass.cpp

```
class myclass
{
public:

    int funct(int val)
    {
       return val + 1;
    }

 ~myclass(){}
};
```

Then, we create a wrapper:

File wrapper.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) myclass* expConst()
{
    return new myclass();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void expDispose(myclass * obj)
{
    delete obj;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int expfunct(myclass* obj, int val)
{   
    return obj->funct(val);
}
```

Now, we come to c#:

```
public class CsClass : IDisposable
{
    //Import the functions from dll

    [DllImport("ExportedLib.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr expDispose(IntPtr obj);

    [DllImport("ExportedLib.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr expConst();

    [DllImport("ExportedLib.dll")]
    public static extern int expfunct(IntPtr obj, int val);

    IntPtr objPtr;
    public CsClass()
    {
        objPtr = expConst();
    }

    public int funct(int q)
    {
        return expfunct(objPtr, q);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        expDispose(objPtr);
    }
}
```

Finally, we ecxecute this by
File:Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CsClass v = new CsClass();
        Console.WriteLine(v.Func(1));
    }
}
```

I tested this simple things and the program printed 2 as it was expected.

The question is, whether the garbage collector of C# will move the created C++ object and, thus, making the objPtr to point to some wrong place in memory?

Are there any other principal obstacles here? I mean some unsolvable problems which make such an approach impossible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an educational question. I will hardly use this code in future.

Comment: Your code is OK, but it is missing `v.Dispose()` call, so native class is not released until the program ends. GC will never move/release created C++ instance, `IntPtr` returned by `expConst` remains valid until `expDispose` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the garbage collector only goes to work for managed memory. Your class created in C++ is not managed memory and will not be touched, for good or for bad. You will need to manage it yourself as you already did.